# Should we exclude external system in component diagram?

Tags: uml

Wanted to know what does the UML version 2 specification recommends about showing external systems in `Component Diagram`.

I checked references (like [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/dec04/bell/index.html)), but couldn't find any specific recommendation for this

Answer (score 1):

OMG (the UML authors) do not recommend any design rules along with the language definition. No matter which language version, be it 1.5, 2.0, 2.1, 2.3 or 2.5.

The IBM document you reference might target process/design views and will be fine for their process description (like RUP or whatever might be en vogue).

What you show in which diagram depends on what you want to show the single readers.